# How to align cell to the right when using CSS Grid?

Tags: html, css

I use grid CSS to align LI as a grid. Below my UL CSS:

```
UL {
    display: grid; 
    grid-template-columns: 250px repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr));
    grid-template-rows:auto;
    grid-gap: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: right;
    text-align: right;
}
```

The content is aligned to the right. But when there are many LI, the last is always aligned to the left.

Below an example with two UL. The first has 3 LI, the second only one.

[image]

What I need to add? I tried many things but it's always the same problem.

The code is a part of two React components.

Shortcuts for the UL:

```
    <div className="shortcuts">
        {(props.title) ? <h2>{props.title}</h2> : null}
        <ul>{ props.children }</ul>
    </div>
```

And shortcut for the LI:

```
    <li className="shortcut">
        <Link to={props.link}>
            <span>{props.icon}</span>
            <span>{props.title}</span>
        </Link>
    </li>
```

Comment: Please share a minimal reproducible code

Comment: Without HTML code it is really hard to give any solution to your problem

Comment: Please provide *rendered* HTML. Right-click an element and select Inspect. Then, in the inspector, right-click the `ul` or whatever and select Copy > Copy outerHTML (on Chromium-based browsers) or Copy > Outer HTML (in Firefox) I don't know about Safari.